# Firebase + Chrome content security policy settings?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firebase, content-security-policy

I'm trying to use Firebase in a Chrome extension background page, but it looks like it's executing inline-scripts, which isn't allowed because of security concerns.

I've currently set the CSP to:

```
{"content_security_policy": 
  "script-src 'self' https://cdn.firebase.com https://<my-subdomain>.firebaseio.com; object-src 'self'"}
```

I'm able to load the initial Firebase script, but upon calling new Firebase('my-firebase-url'), I get the following error:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: ". Uncaught
>   ReferenceError: pRTLPCB is not defined

Is there any work around or advice the Firebase team (or anyone) can give, and maybe an explanation of why scripts are being executed inline?

Comment: Ah, I see I'm not the only one. Yes, the problem is that Firebase constructor is doing some funky magic on call (console.log a new Firebase(URL) to see what I mean.

Comment: Sadly didn't have success from the content side neither - http://d.pr/i/pRMz

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At the time the question was asked, there was a bug preventing Firebase from working in Chrome extensions, but this has now been fixed.

The correct CSP is:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://cdn.firebase.com https://*.firebaseio.com; object-src 'self'"
```

(Note that the wildcard in the domain is important, since Firebase may connect to other subdomains internally.)

For a sample chrome extension using Firebase, see: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-chrome-extension.

Comment: I'm still getting the following: `Refused to load the script 'https://auth.firebase.com...` but adding `https://auth.firebase.com` to the CPS seems to fix it.

Comment: I've been looking for weeks for a solution to this, I forgot to add the cdn.firebase.com, strange because I don't see references to it in my source

Comment: can you help me write the exact same CSP according to manifest version 3?

Answer (score 3):

I'm having a similar problem; you see, Firebase's constructor seems to perform some dom manipulation in order to do some scripting (vague, I know), which triggers Chrome CSP because well, you are not supposed to do that.

I even trying to wrap the constructor through the [Sandbox Pages](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/sandboxingEval.html), but without success (I get an DOM ERR 18, even though my manifest has all permissions). Same happens if you try to do it in a Background Page or a Popup Page for a Page Action/Browser Action.

Alternative? You can inject Firebase as a content script (do it from your manifest), and through [Message Passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) send the callbacks as Chrome.extension.sendMessage. I'm exactly doing this at the moment, so I can tell you how that goes, so far, at least the Firebase constructor works.

Solution? James Tampling reads this and prompts the Firebase team to look up after this :)

**UPDATE:** Injecting Firebase.js as a Content Script doesn't work neither, but the good news is that the Firebase team (reach Andrew Lee) is checking it out.

**UPDATE 2** Firebase team fixed it, and now it does work from a Popup page (both in a Browser Popup or a Page Action one). You need to add the following CSP in your manifest.json though `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://cdn.firebase.com https://*.firebaseio.com https://*.firebaseio.com; object-src 'self'; "` It works wonders after that.

Answer (score 1):

I have a cordova js app, only the below one worked:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="

  default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval';
  script-src  'self' https://www.gstatic.com https://cdn.firebase.com https://*.firebaseio.com; object-src 'self';

  " />
```

hope this helps.